Create a GnuCash Trial Balance Report for one fiscal year
I am trying to create a trial balance report in Gnucash that just covers the last fiscal year. No matter how I change the "start of adjusting period/closing" date it seems to create the report from the date at the opening of the account.
Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Wikipedia defines a Trial Balance as

an internal financial statement that lists the adjusted closing
balances of all the general ledger accounts (both revenue and capital)
contained in the ledger of a business as at a specific date.

Author of quote: Wikipedia contributors
Your accounting textbook will most likely contain a similar definition.
Please note that the Trial Balance is a report as at a specific date, NOT over a given period.  While the Options screen for the Trial Balance report appears to allow for both a "start date" and an "end date", this is likely because the standard Options screen allowed for the input of two dates, and it was simply easier to not re-program the Options screen for this particular report.
In fact, the Trial Balance report only uses the "Date of Report" field as input, and it appears to ignore the "start" date field.  That's to be expected because the Trial Balance reports the net effect of all transactions recorded in the GnuCash file since time began, up to the "Date of Report" date.
